# Child to Parent Communication in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have cascaded components like component inside component, as per LWC documentation in order to avoid mutation the public properties (@api) of child component can't be updated.

```
   comp1
    <template>
         <c-comp2 config={config}></c-comp2>
    </template>

    comp2
    <template>
         <c-comp3 config={config}></c-comp3>
    </template>

    comp3
    ----
    comp3.js
     handleChange(event) {
         fireEvent(this.pageRef, 'searchKeyChange', 'value':event.detail.value});
    }

comp1.js
@api config;
handleSearchKeyChange(searchKey) {
     this.config = searchKey
}
```

In comp3 i am performing some operations and now i want to update the config, i tried to update in the same component but it didn't work.

Created a pubSub event in comp3 and passing changed data to comp1 so that i will have updated data but no luck :(

Please let me know if anyone has faced this issue and how to handle such situation?

Comment: you will need to provide more details as to how you are trying to send an event from cmp3 to cmp1. and please mention where youa re attempting this, communities? lex?

Answer (score 0):

If they are parent and child components then use `component.dispatchEvent()`. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.events

There’s no need to use the reference pub-sub utility.